# Probability of specific result of dice rolling using inclusion-exclusion principle

Tags: probability, combinatorics, inclusion-exclusion

I have two dices and I roll them ten times. What's the probability that I will throw all pairs (i,i), where i=1,...,6 at least once?

I would appreciate any kind of help and hints!

Comment: Do you mean the same pair all the times, or just any pair?

Comment: @bof - yes, that's what i ment

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint: for $i=1,\dots,6$ let $A_i$ be the event "$(i,i)$ never comes up". You want the probability of the complement of the event $(A_1\cup A_2\cup A_3\cup A_4\cup A_5\cup A_6)$. By the in-and-out principle, that probability is equal to
$$1-\sum P(A_i)+\sum P(A_i\cap A_j)-\dots$$
Now $P(A_1)=(\frac{35}{36})^{10},\ P(A_1\cap A_2)=(\frac{34}{36})^{10}$, etc.
That's
$$1-6\left(\frac{35}{36}\right)^{10}+15\left(\frac{34}{36}\right)^{10}-20\left(\frac{33}{36}\right)^{10}+15\left(\frac{32}{36}\right)^{10}-6\left(\frac{31}{36}\right)^{10}+\left(\frac{30}{36}\right)^{10}.$$

Comment: So the answer is $1-\sum P(A_i)+\sum P(A_i\cap A_j)-\dots=1- (\frac{35}{36})^{10} \cdot 6 + (\frac{34}{36})^{10} \cdot 6^2 -\dots$?

Comment: @john1235 Not exactly. Instead of $6^2$ the coefficient is the binomial $\binom62=\frac{6!}{2!4!}=\frac{6\cdot5}{2!}=15$. This is because the sum $\sum P(A_i\cap A_j)$ is taken over $1\le i\lt j\le6$. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inclusion%E2%80%93exclusion_principle

Comment: Oh, I forgot the condition $i<j$. Thank you very much, great solution!